# How can I change change class behaviour on-the-fly?

Tags: java, jvm, on-the-fly

I am trying to edit a class file and make it available to the JVM at runtime.
Is that possible, how can I do it?

For example:

```
main() {
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        NewClass.method();
        //ask user if to continue..
    }
}

public class NewClass() {
    static void method() {
        sysout("hi");
    }
}
```

When this loop is executing, I want to change the file NewClass() and load it in the JVM, so that it prints "bye".

Here is the complete code:

```
try {
    for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 10; iCount++) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter which method:");
        int i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println(i);
        if (i == 1) {
            Called.calledMethod1();
        } else {
            Called.calledMethod2();
        }
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.err.println("Invalid Format!");
}
```

I want to run the main method of one class, and while it is running I want to refer to another class, edit it, and refer the 2nd class's same method and get different output.

I *don't* want to:

1. stop the jvm
2. edit the code
3. run the code again.

I want to

1. edit the code at run time, and get the changes reflected immediately.

Comment: Just to make ur work easier here is the complete code:

   **try{
  for(int iCount=0; iCount<10; iCount++){
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         
         System.out.print("Enter which method:");
             int i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
             System.out.println(i);
             if(i==1){
              Called.calledMethod1();
             }
             else{
              Called.calledMethod2();
             }
         }

  }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            System.err.println("Invalid Format!");
        }**

Comment: You should rather put the code in your question.

Comment: Explain better: you want to be able to load a class dynamically at runtime end execute one of its methods?

Comment: I recommend using a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for reading from console. Is your focus really on class loading or would adding a parameter to the method solve your problem? Be more specific.

Comment: I want to run the main method of one class, while it is running i want to refer to another class, edit it and refer the 2nd class's same method to get different output. Basically i dont want to 1.stop the jvm, 2.edit the code, 3.run the code again.I want to 1.edit the code at run time and get the changes reflected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Java reflection. Using reflection,

1. you load dynamically a class at runtime using [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) [forName method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29).
2. Using [invoke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method on the instance of Class you got,you can call any static method you want giving it's name.

If your class is fixed at design time, you just skeep the first point. Some code:

```
...

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Enter which class:");
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
className=br.readLine()
int results = compiler.run(null, null, null, className+".java");
if(results == 0){

    Class clazz = Class.forName(className+".class");
    System.out.print("Compiled successfully.Enter which method:");
    Object returnValue=clazz.getMethod(br.readLine()).invoke(null);
}
...
```

But beware of security issues: the code above let anyone to execute each static  method of each class accessible at runtime. If security is one of your concern, it's better if you first validate the input received from console and test that they match one of the class methods you whant to make available via console.

**EDIT**:

I better understand your question after I read your comment. In order to compile a class at runtime if you are targeting Java 6, you could use [Java Compiler object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html). I have edit the code to include JavaCompiler usage.

Comment: Enter which class:Called
Compiled successfully.Enter which method:calledMethod1
Oldsysoutmethod1
Enter which class:Called
Compiled successfully.Enter which method:calledMethod1
Oldsysoutmethod1

I wanted to edit the same method and get the Newsysoutmethod1 without re-running the main java program.

I also tried adding a new method to the called java file and putting that method name as the input, but i got NoSuchMethodException

Comment: Is it possible to class.forname the same class file again..by unloading the old class file and loading the same filename with edited content again..

Comment: Pawan:there is no easy solution to unload a Class and reload a changed version. Maybe developing your own classloader, but not an easy stuff. A far easy solution (if it's accetable for you), would be to change the name of your class on each edit, or change its package name.

Comment: i am following the change in class name idea as i wanted tis just for debug purpose:) thanks..